# Catch-All HTML Encoding Entities

Tags: php, html, encoding, character-encoding, page-title

I keep thinking I have come up with the perfect function to tackle my problem, but I eventually find something that breaks it for no apparent reason. I don't fully understand how htmlentities / htmlspecialchars works, or what exactly they convert, so I suppose that would help...

I have a mixture of old and new databases, and user-input

1. - Old databases sometimes characters are encoded with htmlentities()
     inside the data
   - Old databases occasionally contain HTML within content (need stripping)
   - New databases characters are not encoded before insertion
2. - User input could include nasty `<script>` or `&lt;script&gt;` `&amp;lt;script/&amp;gt;`
   - New databases characters are not encoded before insertion

I am trying to create a catch-all function that will make each case (#1 and #2) both safe, and visually appealing

```
function html_enc($text){
  while($text!==html_entity_decode($text,ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8')){
    $text=html_entity_decode($text,ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8');
  }
  $text=strip_tags($text);
  $text=htmlentities($text,ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8');
  return $text;
}
```

I thought I had nailed point #1 it with this function, but when I used it on a pagetitle, it had double quotes in the title, and the page is spitting out `&quot;` instead of ", but the rest of the page is displaying "... I don't understand why the `<title>` element would be different to the normal body... Does anyone know how to solve this small issue? Or suggestion of a better function / improvement?

For point #2 this also seems to be the best solution - I haven't broken this function yet with user input, and standard display on a page / in a textarea

Also on a side note, but in the interest of security; my code is assuming that user input is UTF-8 posted in HTML forms, all of my pages are specified

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Is it possible for a user to submit a different encoding? I would imagine it is, and how would this affect my functions? Is it possible to catch this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By specifying `ENT_HTML5` you've lost the default flags `ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_HTML401`, so quotes are not being decoded.

You'll need `ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_HTML5` or `ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5`.

Comment: Such a simple fix, thanks a lot!